# FirebaseDatabase reference objects with UserAuthentication

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a android application assignment for school and I am having a hard time understanding Firebase Database reference objects for signed in users. It is a chatroom app and users can sign up or login to enter the app. Once in, they can send messages in the chatroom that will be visible to other authorized users that sign in.

**App structure:**

Everything in the app is in a fragment. The main activity calls the Login fragment first. If new user, they can click on sign up and the main activity will replace the login fragment with sign up fragment. Once logged in, the main activity replaces the current fragment with the ChatRoom fragment. This isn't a requirement, but my User authentication steps happen in my MainActivity. That is the only Firebase related task that happens there.

**My progress:**

1. I have the sign up and login sections completed properly.
2. I am able to send a message and that message shows up in the DB under the current user node properly.

**My code:**

All the code I am having issues with is in the ChatRoom fragment.
This is the addEventListener code I have:

```
ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatData; //ChatMessage is my class that takes the message text, sent user, and time.
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); //Root node
DatabaseReference rootReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users"); //Users node
DatabaseReference currentUserReference; //CurrentUser node
FirebaseUser currentUser; //CurrentUser value is obtained from MainActivity after the user signs in

public void onAttach(Context context) {
    //Other event listeners for buttons......

    chatData = new ArrayList<>();
    rootReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatData.clear();
            currentUserReference = rootReference.child(currentUser.getUid());
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapChild : snap.getChildren()) {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = snapChild.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                    chatData.add(chatMessage);
                }
            }
            PopulateListView();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is, when I send a message from say xxx@xxx.com, if there are messages in the DB from say yyy@yyy.com, they get added to xxx's node on top of the message that xxx sends.

Here is my DB JSON:

First message from user xxx:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "xxx" : [ {
      "messageText" : "Hello",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:32:33",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Second message from user xxx:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "xxx" : [ {
      "messageText" : "Hello",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:32:33",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    }, {
      "messageText" : "Hello number 2 from xxx",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:33:16",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    } ]
  }
}
```

First message from user yyy:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "xxx" : [ {
      "messageText" : "Hello",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:32:33",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    }, {
      "messageText" : "Hello number 2 from xxx",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:33:16",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    } ],
    "yyy" : [ {
      "messageText" : "Hello",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:32:33",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    }, {
      "messageText" : "Hello number 2 from xxx",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:33:16",
      "messageUser" : "xxx"
    }, {
      "messageText" : "Hello from yyy",
      "messageTime" : "2019/04/06 16:34:13",
      "messageUser" : "yyy"
    } ]
  }
}
```

How do I fix this issue? I can see exactly why this is happening, it is because of my nested `foreach` loops for all users and all messages within and adding it all to the current user's node. But if I set my listener directly to the child node, my `chatData` ArrayList does not get populated with the messages from other users. How do I work around this?

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you, I will take a look at your tutorial. But this assignment is using Firebase Realtime DB. Can't use Cloud Firestore :(